# Бинарный поиск минимального и максимального элемента. Java

Tags: java

Мой метод находит под каким индексом стоит искомое число.

Мне нужно, чтобы он искал какое число присвоено минимальному индексу, а какое максимальному.

```java
int position;

position = (first + last) / 2;
        
while ((array[position] != item) && (first <= last)) {
    if (array[position] > item) { 
        last = position - 1; 
    } else {
        first = position + 1;   
    }
    position = (first + last) / 2;
}
if (first <= last) {
    System.out.println(item + " является " + ++position + " элементом в массиве");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Только если входной массив отсортирован и содержит повторяющиеся элементы, то можно сначала бинарным поиском определить наличие искомого элемента, а затем можно искать индексы слева и справа.

В более общем случае несортированного входного массива проще отфильтровать индексы за O(N), и вернуть первый и последний индексы.

```java
static int[] firstAndLastIndexes(int x, int ... arr) {
    int[] indexes = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .filter(i -> arr[i] == x)
        .toArray();
    if (indexes.length < 1) {
        return new int[]{-1, -1};
    }
    return new int[]{indexes[0], indexes[indexes.length - 1]};
}
```